# Is there a free version of Sencha touch out there?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm looking for a framework to create touch optimized websites. Sencha and ExtJS look awesome, but don't appear to be free

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sencha touch is available for free under a GPL or a commercial license, both of them at no charge.

See http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/ and http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/.

Answer (score -1):

Ext JS comes with a dual license:

http://extjs.com/products/license.php

So yes, if you open source your application with a license compatible with the GNU GPL license v3.

Comment: the question is about Sencha Touch, not EXT Js.